# three.js - Colors won't appear when I'm trying to load an object

Tags: javascript, three.js, objloader

I'm having a problem with loading objects in three.js. As I said, colors won't appear and the object is black and white!

Here is my code:

Getting Started (I'm not really sure if this section works fine, so I put it here.)

```
const
    width = window.innerWidth - 300,
    height = window.innerHeight,
    scene = new THREE.Scene(),
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, width / height, 1, 1000),
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(),
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement),
    light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, .5),
    loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

camera.position.z = 50;
scene.add(camera);

controls.update();

scene.add(light);

renderer.setSize(width, height);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();

$(window).resize(function () {
    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
});
```

Loading The Object

```
function onProgress(xhr) {
    if (xhr.lengthComputable) {
        const percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
        console.log(Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded');
    }
}

function onError() {
}

const manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
manager.addHandler(/\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader());

new THREE.MTLLoader(manager)

    .setPath('http://localhost/X/assets/models/house/')
    .load('CH_building1.mtl', function (materials) {

        materials.preload();
        new THREE.OBJLoader(manager)
            .setMaterials(materials)

            .setPath('http://localhost/X/assets/models/house/')
            .load('CH_building1.obj', function (object) {

                object.position.y = -10;

                scene.add(object);
            }, onProgress, onError);
    });
```

Sorry if it's too long.

Maybe the object file is broken. And if so, then how can I fix it?

Edit: Is that because of the lights reflection?

Comment: Can you please share the `OBJ`/`MTL` files in this thread?

Comment: @mugen87 Sure: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=03737527042616369249

Comment: Um, I can reproduce on my iMac. Can you please check how the asset is loaded by using `glTF` instead? You can convert your model via https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/obj2gltf.

Comment: Thanks! It worked.

Comment: Um, I just realized that the model is not completely loaded: [Here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=61693531336440252998) It's like some textures aren't loaded. Why is that?

Comment: I found out that some textures are loaded inside the model! This is a screenshot from the inside of it: [Here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=89044211281023458323)

Comment: @Mugen87 (Sorry, forgot to mention.)